# Add a "Copy profile to sister sites" button

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, association

I know we already have the ability to copy profiles **from** a sister site. However, from a usability perspective, if you want to keep your profiles in sync, it requires you to navigate to your profile/accounts page on each site and click that button.

It would be nice to have the button in the reverse direction. Probably, having a "Copy the current profile to all sites" button near "Clear all associations" is a nice place for it.

Comment: How often do you update your profile?

Comment: Marc: with your reasoning, all buttons are unnecessary. When we have such a feature, why don't make it better? Esp. since the primary use case of those three buttons is to keep profile in sync. I think if we had a single "Copy To All" instead of those three, it would have worked better.

Comment: @Mark: I agree with Mehrdad. The "copy profile from ..." seems to be backwards. It would also be nice to have the option of setting a "auto sync profile between sister sites" flag on your profile. I know it is a minor request and a rarely used feature. But it would be nice if i didn't have to worry, at all, about syncing my profiles on all these sites.

Comment: I endorse the request of Mehrdad, specially now the some of the sites proposed at Area 51 are going to enter in beta. At the question "How often you update your profile?" I would answer "More often than today, if we will have this feature" :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Additionally, you can do this with credentials now, too: there's a "Copy {Site} login credentials to all Stack Exchange accounts" button on the **account tab** of your user page now:

[image]

Comment: That's cool! Had to manually go through all my accounts to add Stack Exchange OpenID and that wasn't a good experience. Thanks Jeff!

Answer (score 3):

I just updated my profile on StackOverflow and you're right, having to go to each site to pull the profile across is a minor pain. It makes more sense to have a 'Copy To All' and perhaps change the individual copy buttons to 'Copy To [Site]' etc for more granularity if you want to keep one of the profiles different.

Answer (score 2):

May be it could also be good to have a "dedicated" site where you can manage one profile (used by all sites) and get a single view of your activity on all site. (I mean a cross site user page)