# Should updating profile on one site updates it in other sites?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, overlap

> **Related:**
>
> [Add a “Copy profile to sister sites” button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16640/add-a-copy-profile-to-sister-sites-button)

Hi,

I've updated my SO profile to correct some information and to add some more, but when I see my SO-meta profile, the old information is there.

Shouldn't updating a profile on just one site updates it automatically in sister sites (SU, SF, meta-SO), or at least give an option to do so? It's really annoying to update my profile four times every time I want to edit something.

As I haven't entered the profile information manually the first time I've registered in a sister site, there should be an easy way to get the info from another site.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using a different display name here than in SO (admitedly, it was due to a joke), but I can see reasons to not enforce replication.

You already have a *[copy profile from](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/131760?tab=accounts#sort-top)* button, but maybe a *copy profile to all the rest of associated accounts* would be enough to please your (and many others') need.

Comment: Keep it up smeagols, Meta runs a little amok.

Comment: Amok? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_amok I learn something new every day. Alzeimer makes that easy.

Answer (score 2):

The profiles are separate by design, after all you might want to emphasise different aspects of your work on each site.

Having said that a common core profile with separate specialist sections might be more user friendly.

Comment: Display name, real name, website, age, location, ..etc. are common to all sites. And for me, I also want to have the same "About me" in all sites, but it does make sense to have a specialist zone.

Answer (score 2):

Another option might be to add a 'link profiles' checkbox, which could also be specific between pairs of sites.  Most people probably want the same profile on all sites.