# I updated my name, why don't my user names get replicated over the SE network? Why can I not find this option [easily]?

Tags: feature-request, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add a “Copy profile to sister sites” button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16640/add-a-copy-profile-to-sister-sites-button)

Title says it all.

I've been using the user123456789 format for a long time, and recently changed my name. I tried to "sync up" with the SE profile option, which didn't work. Basically, all the SE sites are on my user123456789 standard, which seems silly when all the accounts are linked together.

Can we get a feature to tie them all together or something?

Answer (score 2):

Go to your profile, click account, scroll down, click **Copy [current_site] profile to all Stack Exchange accounts**.